# Silverlight - validate one single property

Tags: c#, silverlight, entity-framework, validation, mvvm

I'm working on a Silverlight application using MVVM pattern with WCF Ria Services and Entity Framework.
In my metadata class I have validationrules which work perfectly well when I submit the entitydata from the frontend form(with twoway-databinding).

But now I want to validate just one single property in a LostFocus-event in one of my textboxes.

I have tried with this code in the viewmodel class:

```
Validator.ValidateProperty(myEntity.FirstName,
  new ValidationContext(myEntity, null, null)
  {
    MemberName = "FirstName"
  });
```

The code runs, but nothing happens. No exception, even if the property FirstName is empty(have tried other properties as well). As I mentioned the validation works when I submit the form to the EF.

Does anyone have tips on how to validate just a single property without submitting everything?

Answer (score 0):

In your metadata before ur property add this **[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter FirstName.")]** and then in the control whr u have bind the property add this thing **Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True**

this might help u out :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I have already this code in place. As I mentioned everything works fine when pushing the submitbutton. Seems like my code above(Validator.ValidateProperty) doesn't affect the validationprocess. In examples I've only seen ValidateProperty in the metadata-class, not in the viewmodel class like I'm trying to.

Comment: do u want that property to be not null or required if u use required property like **"[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter FirstName.")]"** will work properly on lostfocus i have tired this and its working properly..

Comment: Well, I want it to have a value(required). And I've also tried other properties(one where I'm validating a date being only 10 days old) with no luck. But again, everything works great on submit. I've also checked the value of myEntity.myProperty before validating to be sure the value is not valid. My question is, can I use Validator.ValidateProperty in the viewmodel context or does this only work in metadataclasses?